# Нужно рассчитать рабочее время с учетом временных рамок

Tags: php

Есть рабочее время, например с 9:00 до 18:00.
Есть данные, когда рабочий приступил к работе (например 30 числа в 10:00)
и когда он закончил работу (например 2 числа в 16:30).
Нужно рассчитать сколько часов он проработал.

Изначально думал просто брать второе число, 
отнимать от первого,
если разница один день, то просто считать от первой точки до конца рабочего дня плюс начало рабочего дня до второй точки.
Если разница 2 дня и больше, то прибавлять полный рабочий день.
Но тут нюанс, что начинает он в конце месяца, а заканчивает в начале,
то-есть еще нужно высчитывать разницу месяцев, сколько дней в предыдущем месяце и тд ...

Возможно есть вариант попроще.

Comment: А потом ещё учитывать високосные годы. Не избретайте велосипед. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-diff.php

Comment: Выходные учитываются?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов да, все дни недели учитываются

Comment: Тогда вообще не вижу в чем проблема.

Comment: Ну так есть же [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php), там метод `modify`. Всё считает сам - пробуйте.

Comment: @Gedweb и что же он считает?

Answer (score 0):

Вот как то так набросал -

```
$start = strtotime('31.01.2009 9:00:00');
$end = strtotime('31.01.2009 10:00:00');

$hours = (($end - strtotime("midnight",$end)) + (strtotime("tomorrow",$start) - $start) + (strtotime("midnight",$end) - strtotime("tomorrow",$start)) - 15*60*60*round(($end - $start) / (60 * 60 * 24)))/3600;
```

PS: Добавлю, что данный код считает часы с учетом 9 часового рабочего дня без проверки времени начала и конца рабочего дня. Т.е. может быть использован для подсчета рабочих часов для рабочего дня с 8 до 17, с 9 до 18, с 10 до 19 и т.д. Начальные параметры нужно контролировать на входе.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php) и даже 29 февраля не станет сюрпризом, а если понадобится ещё и часовые пояса есть.

Задача вообще интересная, как понял нас интересует только рабочие часы в указанном отрезке времни.

```php
const WORKDAY_BEGIN = [9, 0]; // 9:00
const WORKDAY_END = [18, 0]; // 18:00

function hoursDelta(\DateTime $begin, \DateTime $end): float
{
    $workDayBegin = (clone $begin)->setTime(...WORKDAY_BEGIN);
    $flawBegin = $begin->diff($workDayBegin);

    $workDayEnd = (clone $end)->setTime(...WORKDAY_END);
    $flawEnd = $workDayEnd->diff($end);

    // полных дней, на количество рабочих часов
    $hoursDelta = $end->diff($begin, true)->days * ($workDayEnd->diff($workDayBegin)->h);

    // вычитаем недоработку часов
    $hoursDelta -= (float) $flawBegin->h + $flawEnd->h;
    // и если нужно минут
    $hoursDelta -= ($flawBegin->i + $flawEnd->i) / 60;

    return $hoursDelta;
}

$result = hoursDelta(
    new \DateTime('30-05-2019 10:00'),
    new \DateTime('02-06-2019 16:30')
);

echo $result; // 24.5
```